# How to remove xml "&" symbol

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, xml-parsing

i am parasing xml file to dataset.I getting error if xml data contain "&" or some special char how to remove that?

How to remove "&" from below tag?

xml

```
 < department departmentid=1 name="pen & Note" >
```

$

`string departmentpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Department.xml");
    DataSet departmentDS = new DataSet();

    System.IO.FileStream dpReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream(departmentpath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

    try
    {
        departmentDS.ReadXml(dpReadXml);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //logg
    }`

Comment: Is the 'xml' coming from a source you don't control?  The text you showed is malformed xml, which is the underlying problem here.  If you need to tolerate the malformed xml, then you'll have to look at transforming the incoming text.  That, in turn, requires you to investigate and define the various ways that the input text might not conform to XML and how you would like to 'correct' these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be C#. But do add the correct language tag!

There are five special characters that often require escaping within XML documents. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) SO question.

There are two possibilities:

- Let your `DataSet::ReadXML` method handle these special characters *[Recommended]*
- Change all special characters from your input files  *[Not recommended]*

The second method is not recommended since you cannot possibly always control the incoming data (and you probably would be wasting time pre-processing them if you do want to). In order for `ReadXML` to properly parse the special characters you will need to define a proper encoding too in your input XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it with `&amp;`

Comment: This wouldn't be a recommended way. See my answer below as to why.

Comment: Thanks gabizish,How to replace xml? if i get xml from URL.

Comment: @laksh - if the XML comes from a third-party URL with `&` symbols in it, then you should notify the provider that they are providing invalid XML. In the meanwhile, you may have to do some post-processing on it to replace the `&` with `&amp;` yourself. It should be a fairly simple string-replace function to achieve it, but be careful not to replace other existing entity codes (ie like `&amp;` or `&gt;` etc that begin with `&`).

Answer (score 2):

The culture of XML is that the person who creates the XML is responsible for delivering well-formed XML that conforms to the spec; the recipient is expected to reject it if they get it wrong. So by trying to repair bad XML and turn it into good XML you are going against the grain. It's like getting served bad food in a restaurant: you should complain, rather than asking the people at the next table how to make it digestible.

The input you've provided has a lot more wrong with it than the ampersands. It's hardly recognizable as XML at all. You're never going to turn this mess into a robust data flow.